# Why does my RPi reboot every ~15 minutes?

Tags: crash, reboot

I installed on my RPi 3 the latest Raspberry OS (`Linux rpi-datacenter 5.10.63-v7+ #1488 SMP Thu Nov 18 16:14:44 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux`) and I have no idea why it reboots on its own every ~15 minutes. Below is an overview of the last few unintended reboots (I left the Rpi alone, no connection of any kind).

First I cleaned all the journals and rebooted (to start clean and set a timestamp)

```
root@rpi-datacenter ~# date && journalctl -m --rotate && journalctl -m --vacuum-time=1s && reboot
Fri 24 Dec 13:27:34 CET 2021
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/1988e04f6eb24e47b288d64717ea3cb6/system@da8c55720d1d413e815a6f70cf2becfd-00000000000002af-0005d3e3784ebf4e.journal (8.0M).
Vacuuming done, freed 8.0M of archived journals from /var/log/journal/1988e04f6eb24e47b288d64717ea3cb6.
Vacuuming done, freed 0B of archived journals from /run/log/journal.
Vacuuming done, freed 0B of archived journals from /var/log/journal.
```

Then I waited some time to let the RPi reboot several times on its own without any intervention

Logging back to the Rpi, this is the reboots history:

```
root@rpi-datacenter ~# journalctl --list-boots
-4 574969fdfb0740c78f4d27da07db9806 Fri 2021-12-24 13:27:34 CET—Fri 2021-12-24 13:27:40 CET
-3 4f487d020b504271bb202e84fb4dd20d Fri 2021-12-24 13:27:40 CET—Fri 2021-12-24 13:28:32 CET
-2 b04cd0334ac149bfa61a0c8441686166 Fri 2021-12-24 13:31:51 CET—Fri 2021-12-24 13:36:23 CET
-1 7af98da957d24037a5a588f8139499df Fri 2021-12-24 13:43:59 CET—Fri 2021-12-24 13:48:42 CET
 0 7624d634b646401996432bb8c24579b2 Fri 2021-12-24 13:56:15 CET—Fri 2021-12-24 14:06:55 CET
```

I cannot find anything strange in the logs, except that they suddenly stop right before a reboot. The logs are at https://pastebin.com/3VNH1ci0 due to their size

I though that it may be the power, seems that no:

```
root@rpi-datacenter ~# vcgencmd get_throttled
throttled=0x0
```

I thought that it may be the temperature, seems that no:

```
root@rpi-datacenter ~# vcgencmd measure_temp
temp=53.7'C
```

I thought that it may be a disk space problem, no:

```
root@rpi-datacenter ~# df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       15178032 1537304  12992592  11% /
devtmpfs          340904       0    340904   0% /dev
tmpfs             472488       0    472488   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             188996     648    188348   1% /run
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
/dev/mmcblk0p1    258095   49269    208827  20% /boot
tmpfs              94496       0     94496   0% /run/user/0
```

Any other ideas? Is there a better way I can debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider checking crontab and see if, by any chance, there is some sort of timer set to reboot your Pi.
You can use:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

in your terminal and check it out.
If possible leave a screenshot of the crontab.

Comment: No, the crontab is empty and the reboots are not exactly every X minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the power splitter (PoE from my switch) with a true power supply and the RPi is now stable.

It means that it may either be a splitter problem, or PoE on the switch (though I have an AP powered by the same switch and it is very stable)

Comment: What else have you got connected (if anything) to the PoE system on your LAN? There are limits to what you can take from a PoE system - and if you exceed them then something has got to give. Also - you don't seem to have mentioned that you were using PoE and that is a big piece of information to leave out! Is it one of the official Foundation ones and what have you got supplying the power?

Comment: @SlySven: I also have a Ubiquity AP. Your points are very pertinent - but since the RPi does not mention any power-related issues it is down to either the splitter (a no-name one), or the PoE itself (but the AP is always fine).

Comment: I was thinking that the item injecting power into the PoE system decided that either the RPi bit was taking too much power and switched it off after a preset time (i.e. 15 minutes) or that cumulatively *everything* that was on the system took to much and again the source of the power decided to remove the overload by switching the power off to the RPi. If that happened I am not sure there would be much log evidence in the RPi - as the power was removed before it could log that there wasn't any power...

Answer (score 1):

One way to diagnose this is to check whether these reboots get registered in the list shown by `last reboot`. If they are, software is likely at play, if not, the reboots are probably hardware-related.

Another test is to install a vanilla system with no modifications whatsoever and see how it runs: something as notable as a reboot every 15 min. is unlikely to go unnoticed in a release. If you get such issues on a vanilla system, they are, again, most likely hardware-related. Installing a different system (e.g. Raspbian) and seeing the same problem is a near-100% confirmation of a hardware issue.